# Applying master theorem

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

$T(n)=21n+7T(3n/11)·7+8\log (n!)+\sqrt{\log n}+n^2$
I am trying to apply master theorem to this recurrence relation. I know that $\log(n!) \leq (n+1)\log(n+1)-n$. Hence I am thinking that $f(n) \in O(n^2)$. Then I computed $n^{\log_{\frac{11}{3}}49}$ and compared it to $n^2$ and couldn't find an $\epsilon$ which makes $f(n) \in O(n^{\log_{\frac{11}{3}}49- \epsilon} ) $.
How can I find this $\epsilon$ or does it exist? Thank you!

Comment: Since each term of $f$ is bounded above by $n^2$, it is true that $f(n) \in O(n^2)$. Since $\log_{11/3} 49 = 2\log_{3.\overline{6}}7 > 2\cdot 1 = 2$, anything that is $O(n^2)$ is automatically $O(n^{\log_{11/3} 49 -\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon \le \log_{11/3} 49 - 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Regarding the recurrence

$$
T\left( n\right)  = c T\left(\frac{a}{b}n \right) + f(n)
$$

with $\{a,b,n\}\in \mathbb{N}^+$, $a,b$ relative primes, $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Considering now $n = b^m q$ with $\{q,m\}\in \mathbb{N}^+$ and $q \not|\; b$, the path from $n = b^m q$ to extinction is

$$
\{b^m q, b^{m-1}a q,\cdots, b^{m-k}a^k q,\cdots,b a^{m-1}q,a^m q\}
$$

so calling now $T(a^m q)= T_{q_0}$ we have

$$
T(b^m q) = c^m T_{q_0}+\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}c^{m-k}f(a^{m-k}b^k q)
$$